# Using DataPower CLI to produce a list of services (WSP & MPGW) on an application domain

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am looking for a way to produce a list of services on a Datapower domain using a script (the ultimate goal is automatically shutting down active probes after every workday). I have found the way to shut down a probe on an individual known service in CLI, but not the way to access a list of services. Is it possible, or is it better to focus on maintaining a list of services the script can access?

P.S. obviously, a list of active probes on the domain would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

Like you have done, it is only possible to do every process at a time only using log target and event triggers and executing code. The way you are asking is possible by may be some automation tool or monitoring tools.